# How to get original value of SQLAlchemy custom type?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

**My question in short:** Is it possible to access the original value of a custom type in SQLAlchemy?

My implementation of the custom type:

```
class JSONDocument(TypeDecorator):
    # override field
    impl = JSON

    # Write
    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if value is not None:
            req = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps({'data': value}))
            uri = req.json()['uri']
            value = uri
        return value

    # Read
    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if value is not None:
            uri = value
            req = requests.get(uri)
            value = req.json()['data']
        return value
```

My table model:

```
class SomeTable(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # The column with large json data
    json_data = db.Column(JSONDocument)
```

Whenever I try to update or insert a row, which will write to the `json_data` column as a result, SQLAlchemy will call `JSONDocument`'s `process_bind_param`. It will then do a POST API call to create a new data entry in my NoSQL table and update the `json_data` column in my SQL table to the returned URI.

Whenever I try to access the `json_data` column, it will do a GET API call to the URI stored in my SQL table and return the actual JSON data stored in my NoSQL table.

**My question:** How can I get the URI stored in my SQL table covered by `JSONDocument`? I want to do a DELETE API call to the old URI whenever I update a `json_data`.

I've tried using SQLAlchemy's Mapping event callbacks but I'm still not able to get the URI behind my custom type.

Please let me know if I'm not asking my question clear enough. Any suggestions or ideas are appreciated.

**Summary of the task I am trying to do:**

I have a Postgresql database (RDS) table that has columns: `id`(int), `json_data`(string), `other_columns`...

Since the `json_data` column is taking too much storage, I'm working on moving the data in that column to other NoSQL database (DynamoDB). I implemented a RESTful API server for updating, inserting and soft deleting data in my NoSQL table.

I want to implement an SQLAlchemy custom type that will automatically call my API methods whenever my app tries to access the `json_data` column in other Python code.

Comment: Do you mean returning the uri along the value during read?

Comment: Not quite, I only want the value during regular read. By regular read, I mean something like `result = SomeTable.query.first().json_data`. I'm asking if there's something like `result.raw_value`, so that I can get the URI behind the custom type.

Comment: There are multiple ways how to solve this, but there is no "build in" solution as both process bind and process result were written by you. 1st - you can do instead of "uri = value" use "self.uri = value" and istead of "req = requests.get(uri)" use "req = requests.get(self.uri)". This way uri should be accessible by "result.uri". Second option is to use plain SQL through session.execute(). Or even you can create another class which again inherits from the JSONDocument and you again override process_result_value :)

Comment: @PeterMajko Thanks a lot for the suggestions! I actually did try the 1st method, but it seems like each custom type instances share the same `JSONDocument` instance, since when I update the 'self.uri' of one row's `json_data`, the 'self.uri' of other rows' `json_data` will also be updated to the same thing. Can you elaborate on the last method you mentioned? Or is there any documents or articles I can checkout to see how it works? Thanks!

Comment: When I wrote my previous comment I wasn't able to try it out. Now I got to pc and I see that unfortunately my "ideas" were wrong. I am sorry. Because when you access the SameTable.json_data it gives already data type instance instead of TypeDecorator one. Could you use something like "return value, uri", then when you access some_table_instance.json_data[0] you get your JSON and some_table_instance.json_data[1] you get uri. Would this be suitable?

Comment: @PeterMajko It's all good. The custom type of SQLAlchemy is quite confusing to me at first too. Changing the way to access `json_data` is something I'm trying to avoid, since most of the usage of `SomeTable` in my app was implemented by other programmers, and I'm trying to move things to NoSQL database without having to change all the code that access `json_data`.

Comment: I'm now thinking about adding one additional column that simply stores a copy of the URI of the `json_data` and I'll declare it without custom type. In this way, if I figure out when and how to update the additional column, I think everything might work, but, ofc, I'll have to do some unit testing. Anyway, I really appreciate your help and this discussion is really helpful to me. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you though about getting rid of custom TypeDecorator and move your logic to SomeTable similar to this using properties?

```
class SomeTable(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # The column with large json data
    _uri = db.Column(db.JSON)

    @property
    def json_data(self):
        if self._uri is not None:
            req = requests.get(self._uri)
            return req.json()['data']
        else:
            return None

    @json_data.setter
    def json_data(self, value):
        req = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps({'data': value}))
        self._uri = req.json()['uri']

    @property
    def uri(self):
        return self._uri
```

Comment: Wow. It works so well using properties! It's amazing that the code we used to read and write properties and columns are exactly the same (plz let me know if this is not true). I'll have to do some unit testing to make sure everything works well tho. Thank you so much for the suggestions! :)